# How to replace NULL values in one column to 0 (of a very large table) without creating a new column of the desired results added to the table in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to replace all of the NULL values to 0 in a column of a big table in HIVE.

However, every time I try to implement some code I end up generating a new column to the table. The column I am trying to change/modify still exists and still has the NULL values but the new column that is automatically generated (i.e. _c1) is what I want the column I am trying to modify, to look like.

I tried to run a **COALESCE** but that also ended up generating a new column. I also tried to implement a **CASE WHEN**, but the same results ensued.

```
Select *, 
CASE WHEN columnname IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE columnname
END
from tablename;
```

> Also tried

```
SELECT coalesce(columnname, CAST(0 AS BIGINT)) FROM tablename
```

I would just like to update the table with the other columns being as is but the column I want to modify still has its original name but instead of NULL values it has 0's that replaced them.

**I don't want to generate a new column but modify an existing one.**
How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert overwrite ..` option.

```
insert overwrite table tablename
select c1,c2,...,coalesce(columnname,0) as columnname
from tablename
```

Note that you have to specify all the other column names required in `select`.